# UITableViewCell does not commit editing style correctly [iOS7]

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I'm using the "swipe-to-delete" functionality in my `UITableView`. It worked without problems in the past.

Since I updated my project to iOS7, the cell does not exit the "swiped" state. So when I click the delete button, `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` gets called, but it does not hide the button again.

Do I need to do that manually since iOS7? If yes, what method do I have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having same problem. The problem is the delegate method `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` it isn't more called (don't know why).

the way that I found is call the `[tableview reloadData]` inside of `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` instead of in `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` . This works in iOS 6 and 7.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [myDataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [myTable reloadData];
    }       
}
```

Comment: Reloading the whole tableView would be overkill. Use `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. This gives you the advantage of making a smooth animation possible. It still sucks :(

Comment: I have same issue. This answer works, however I need to animate the row.